# How to compute the maximum value of a trace function?

Tags: optimization, matrix

The problem is given by:

$$ \text{maximize}_{W} \ \operatorname{Trace}(W^T H W L) \tag{1}  $$
$$s.t: \  W^TW=I$$

where $W \in R^{n \times n}$ is a matrix variable and $H,L$ are constant square positive definite matrices that have the size of $n$.

I am thinking of converting it into a generalized eigen decomposition problem like other linear dimensionality reduction methods. However, in most of previous work on those problems, the objective function will be similar to $W A W^T $. The appearance of matrix $L$ in (1) makes the problem difficult.

Any advice ?

Comment: A suitably chosen reflection (in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$) can reduce $L$ to a matrix with at most one non-zero value without changing the trace of this product, thereby greatly simplifying the problem.